# Limit Converges to $1$ by some identity

Tags: limits

Let $x_n>0$ and satisfy 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(x_n^8+x_n)=2.$$
Can we show that $x_n$ converges to $1$? 
I could only bound $x_n$ by $2$...

Comment: Consider the polynomial $f(x) = x^8 + x -2$, can you prove $1$ is its only root over $(0, +\infty)$? Is $f(x)$ increasing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x^8+x$ has a positive derivative $8x^7+1$ and is continuously invertible.

If $f(x_n)$ converges to $2$, then $x_n$ converges to $f^{-1}(2)$.

Solve $x^8+x=2$, it has at most one positive solution.

Comment: Which assumes that $(x_n)$ *converges*.

Comment: As $x_n^8+x_n$ converges to some $y$ and $f(x)=x^8+x$ is invertible, $x_n$ converges to $f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: In other words: this, which is missing from the post, needs some justification.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

- Let $p:x\mapsto x+x^8$, then the function $p$ is strictly increasing on $x\geqslant0$ with $p(1)=2$ and $p'(x)\geqslant1$ for every $x\geqslant0$
- Thus, $|x-1|\leqslant|p(x)-2|$ for every $x\geqslant0$
- Now, use that $p(x_n)\to2$ when $n\to\infty$ and that $x_n\geqslant0$ for every $n$

Comment: To say $|p(x)-2| < \varepsilon \Longrightarrow |x-1| < \varepsilon/20$, you rather need a minoration on $|p'|$

Comment: @user10676 Indeed, thanks for notifying me.